# Upgrade from 8.04 to 10.04, "no release found"

Tags: upgrade, 8.04

I've run the following commands as root:

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
apt-get dist-upgrade
```

all work fine, but then i run

```
do-release-upgrade
```

and it says "no new release".  This makes no sense as I've upgraded a clone of this machine in the past and it went straight to 10.04.  I can get out to the internet fine.  Any ideas why this might be?

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/q/91815/44179

Comment: I tried  http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu as the source as well, so I don't think this is duplicate.  Also, I did the upgrade on the clone only a couple of days ago.

Comment: Not a duplicate since 8.04 is technically still supported for another month or two.

Answer (score 1):

What I would probably do is just download a 10.04 ISO file and burn to a disk or usb. Then when you boot the computer from the disk, one of the installation options is to upgrade your current version to the version on the disk. It will keep all of your files and settings. I can't honestly say I've ever done it before, but I know it's an option. It also should take less time than an online upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Do make sure that in Software Sources, under the "Updates" tab, you have "Long-term support releases" selected in the dropdown menu below the "Release Upgrade" header. This will allow you to upgrade to the next LTS release in the terminal or with GUI. If I had a dime for every time I forgot to set this and missed the upgrade by a few days.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a proxy server, set the system wide proxy variable:

```
export http_proxy=http://<your-proxy-server>:<port>
```